# dmesg is showing apparmor="DENIED"

Tags: apparmor, dmesg

I'm following a set of instructions and to validate I need to type the following command:

```
dmesg | grep IOMMU
```

Nothing appears. But then I tried just `dmesg` and it only shows a lot of the following line

```
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor"
```

It appears AppArmor is preventing what `dmesg` is supposed to show on the console.

How do I invoke the command `dmesg` without AppArmor interfering?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+bug/1791454